# Check # of JDBC Connections in Use

Tags: jdbc, jboss, connection-pooling

My application has been setup with jdbc connection pool in JBoss, is there any way I can check the # of connections currently in use while running a particular method?

```
<min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using JBoss AS7.

I am not sure if I understand what you mean by "running a particular method". You can run the following CLI command to get data source run time statistics assuming you have statistics enabled on the particular datasource:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=YourDataSource:read-resource(include-runtime=true,recursive=true)
```

You will get a number of metrics returned, the one that will tell you current number of connections is the attribute `ActiveCount`. The `MaxUsedCount` is also a good metric to observe since that will tell what was the maximum # of connections that was checked out of the pool so you can determine if your `max-pool-size` is configured properly for your load requirements.

Alternatively, you can get these stats from JConsole as well by running the `jconsole.sh` (linux/unix) or `jconsole.bat` (windows) scripts from the bin directory under JBoss installation.